# JPA native query resultset mapping not working?

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to map native query results to POJO class and facing the below error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown entity: com.cvrr.btq.model.LossDetails; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.cvrr.btq.model.LossDetails
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:303) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:214) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy270.listLossDetails(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.cvrr.btq.service.impl.BotiqueServiceImpl.listLossDetails(BotiqueServiceImpl.java:45) ~[BotiqueServiceImpl.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201) ~[spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy271.listLossDetails(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.cvrr.btq.controller.BotiqueController.listLossDetails(BotiqueController.java:44) ~[BotiqueController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.cvrr.btq.model.LossDetails
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1146) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.11.Final.jar:4.2.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.getSQLLoadable(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.11.Final.jar:4.2.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processRootReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:377) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.11.Final.jar:4.2.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:356) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.11.Final.jar:4.2.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.process(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.11.Final.jar:4.2.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLCustomQuery.<init>(SQLCustomQuery.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.11.Final.jar:4.2.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.<init>(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.11.Final.jar:4.2.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.11.Final.jar:4.2.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.11.Final.jar:4.2.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:232) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.11.Final.jar:4.2.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.11.Final.jar:4.2.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:268) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.11.Final.jar:4.2.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy277.getResultList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.cvrr.btq.dao.impl.BotiqueDAOImpl.listLossDetails(BotiqueDAOImpl.java:107) ~[BotiqueDAOImpl.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) ~[spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Oct 18, 2015 4:09:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringDispatcher] in context with path [/Botique] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown entity: com.cvrr.btq.model.LossDetails; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.cvrr.btq.model.LossDetails] with root cause
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.cvrr.btq.model.LossDetails
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1146)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.getSQLLoadable(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processRootReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.process(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLCustomQuery.<init>(SQLCustomQuery.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.<init>(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:268)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy277.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at com.cvrr.btq.dao.impl.BotiqueDAOImpl.listLossDetails(BotiqueDAOImpl.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy270.listLossDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.cvrr.btq.service.impl.BotiqueServiceImpl.listLossDetails(BotiqueServiceImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy271.listLossDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.cvrr.btq.controller.BotiqueController.listLossDetails(BotiqueController.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My entity class has annotation as:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "LossDetailsMapping",
        entities = @EntityResult(
                entityClass = LossDetails.class,
                fields={
                    @FieldResult(name = "billId", column = "billId"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "billSrlNum", column = "billSrlNum"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "totalInItems", column = "totalInItems"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "totalInAmount", column = "totalInAmount"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "totalSoldItems", column = "totalSoldItems"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "totalSoldAmount", column = "totalSoldAmount"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "remItems", column = "remItems"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "loss", column = "loss")
                }
                )
        )
public class LossDetails {
//setter, getter are here
}
```

and my JPA query is:

```
LIST_LOSS_PROFIT_DETAILS="SELECT sd_data.bill_id as billId ,"
            + "  sd_data.bill_srl_no as billSrlNum ," + "  sd_data.total_act_qnt as totalInItems ,"
            + "  sd_data.tot_act_rt as totalInAmount ," + "  NVL(ssd_data.sold_qnt,0) as totalSoldItems ,"
            + "  NVL(ssd_data.sold_act_rt,0) as totalSoldAmount,"
            + "  sd_data.total_act_qnt-NVL(ssd_data.sold_qnt,0) as remItems,"
            + "  sd_data.tot_act_rt-NVL(ssd_data.sold_act_rt,0) as loss" + " FROM" + "  (SELECT sd.BILL_ID,"
            + "    sd.BILL_SRL_NO," + "    (sd.QUANTITY_PCS -sd.REVERSED_QUANTITY)                AS total_act_qnt,"
            + "    (sd.QUANTITY_PCS -sd.REVERSED_QUANTITY)*sd.ACTUAL_RATE AS tot_act_rt" + "  FROM stock_details sd"
            + "  ) sd_data" + " LEFT OUTER JOIN" + "  (SELECT ssd.bill_id," + "    ssd.BILL_SRL_NO,"
            + "    SUM(ssd.QUANTITY_PCS -ssd.REVERSED_PCS)                AS sold_qnt,"
            + "    SUM((ssd.QUANTITY_PCS-ssd.REVERSED_PCS)*ssd.SOLD_RATE) AS sold_act_rt"
            + "  FROM stock_sold_details ssd" + "  WHERE ssd.REVERSED_PCS NOT IN ('C')"
            // + " --AND ssd.SOLD_DATE > '01-JUL-2015'"
            + "  GROUP BY ssd.BILL_ID," + "    ssd.BILL_SRL_NO" + "  ORDER BY ssd.BILL_ID," + "    ssd.BILL_SRL_NO"
            + "  ) ssd_data" + " ON sd_data.bill_id     =ssd_data.bill_id"
            + " AND sd_data.BILL_SRL_NO=ssd_data.BILL_SRL_NO" + " where sd_data.bill_id= ? "
            + " order by sd_data.bill_id," + "  sd_data.bill_srl_no";
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(LIST_LOSS_PROFIT_DETAILS,LossDetails.class);
List<LossDetails> lossDtls = query.getResultList();
```

Could any one you please help me what mistake I am doing during this code?

Comment: can you give your bean?

Comment: Is your LossDetails class, mapped with @Entity?

Comment: updated my bean class

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways to map the result set of a native SQL queries to classes - either via `@EntityResult` and `@ConstructorResult`

**@EntityResult**
It is possible to retrieve managed entities from native SQL queries. You can map between values returned via SQL query to entity attributes. For example you have an entity class `LossDetails.class` and is mapped to `LOSS_DETAILS` table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="LOSS_DETAILS)
public class LossDetails {
    @Id
    private Long billId;

    private String billSrlNum;

    private Integer totalInItems;

    private Double totalInAmount;

    private Integer totalSoldItems;

    private Double totalSoldAmount;

    private Integer remItems;

    private Double loss;
}
```

Then, for example your native SQL query will return the ff. columns:

```
BILL_ID, BILL_SRL_NO, TOTAL_ACT_QNT, TOTAL_ACT_RT, SOLD_QNT, SOLD_ACT_RT, REM_ITEMS, LOSS
```

Notice, that the column names did not exactly match the attribute names of your entity class `LossDetails`. For this, you need to specify your `@SqlResultSetMapping` like this:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="LossDetailsMapping",
    entities=@EntityResult(
        entityClass=LossDetails.class,
        fields={
            @FieldResult(name="billId", column="BILL_ID"),
            @FieldResult(name="billSrlNum", column="BILL_SRL_NO"),
            @FieldResult(name="totalInItems", column="TOTAL_ACT_QNT"),
            @FieldResult(name="totalInAmount", column="TOTAL_ACT_RT"),
            @FieldResult(name="totalSoldItems", column="SOLD_QNT"),
            @FieldResult(name="totalSoldAmount", column="SOLD_ACT_RT"),
            @FieldResult(name="remItems", column="REM_ITEMS"),
            @FieldResult(name="loss", column="LOSS")
        }
    )
)
```

If your SQL columns and entity attributes exactly matches the names, then you don't need to enumerate the fields. Just like this:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="LossDetailsMapping",
    entities=@EntityResult(
        entityClass=LossDetails.class)
)
```

Note that is possible that the native SQL query selects from another table (different from the table mapped to the entity) as long as the resulting columns would be mapped to each entity attribute and their types are compatible.

To use the declared result-set mapping in creating the native query, just reference it by its name. Example below:

```
private String LIST_LOSS_PROFIT_DETAILS = "...YOUR NATIVE SQL QUERY HERE...";

Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(LIST_LOSS_PROFIT_DETAILS, "LossDetailsMapping");
List lossDtls = query.getResultList();
```

---

**@ConstructorResult**

If your purpose is only to map the results of your native SQL to a POJO or bean class, and that bean doesn't necessarily have to be managed by doing save/update/remove operations on it, then you don't need an entity class. You can actually map SQL result set columns to just plain Java objects. I believe this is want you desired to use. With JPA 2.1 version, you have the ability to construct **non-entity types** from native queries thru `@ConstructorResult`.

Here is an example:

```
public class LossDetails {

    public LostDetails(Long billId, String billSrlNum, 
        Integer totalInItems, Double totalInAmount, 
        Integer totalSoldItems, Double totalSoldAmount,
        Integer remItems, Double loss) {
        this.billId = billId;
        this.billSrlNum = billSrlNum;
        this.totalInItems = totalInItems;
        this.totalInAmount = totalInAmount;
        this.totalSoldItems = totalSoldItems;
        this.totalSoldAmount = totalSoldAmount;
        this.remItems = remItems;
        this.loss = loss;
    }

    private Long billId;

    private String billSrlNum;

    private Integer totalInItems;

    private Double totalInAmount;

    private Integer totalSoldItems;

    private Double totalSoldAmount;

    private Integer remItems;

    private Double loss;
}
```

Notice that `LossDetails` is just a POJO, not annotated with `@Entity`. Also notice the presence of the constructor. The sql resultset mapping using `@ConstructorResult` will use this constructor to create the POJO out of the native SQL query results.

Per JPA spec:

> All columns corresponding to arguments of the intended constructor
>   must be specified using the columns element of the ConstructorResult
>   annotation in the same order as that of the argument list of the
>   constructor.

So here's a sample use of `@ConstructorResult`:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="LossDetailsMapping",
    classes={
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass=LossDetails.class,
            columns={
                @ColumnResult(name="billId", type=Long.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="billSrlNum", type=String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="totalInItems", type=Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="totalInAmount", type=Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="totalSoldItems", type=Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="totalSoldAmount", type=Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="remItems", type=Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="loss", type=Double.class)
            })
    }
)
```

I'm not sure which JPA version you are using 2.0 or 2.1. **`@ConstructorResult` is only supported in JPA 2.1 version**. Check if you can import `java.persistence.ConstructorResult` without getting any compilation error.

Comment: If I need to specify the Entity, what should be the table name?

Comment: What table are you querying from in your Native SQL query? That should be the table that will be mapped into your Entity class. Also, you haven't actually used the resultset mapping you just declared in your createNativeQuery call. See code I posted.

Comment: My result set mapping "LossDetailsMapping" is defined in bean annotation as I mentioned above. My native sql is querying multiple tables

Comment: Maybe you have an incorrect understanding on how to use @SqlResultSetMapping. Please post the entire native SQL query you are using, from there I can perhaps suggest what you need to do. But before I do that, have you tried annotating you LossDetails with @Entity?

Comment: You said are querying in multiple tables. Then making LossDetails an entity probably won't help. Then I suggest use `@ConstructorResult`, because by using `@EntityResult`, the class that you are mapping must be an entity.

Comment: Can you please explain me when can we use native query and usage of @SqlResultSetMappings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92645/discussion-between-ish-and-venkata-ramireddy-ch).

Comment: In my case, I'm trying to just do a select on a sql view and map that to my pojo / projection. I'm getting the error despite using ConstructorResult. My guess - the view is not a managed entity. Is there a chance to do this somehow with views?